# Is it acceptable to copy verbatim the description of a software package?

Tags: copyright

I just read an article where the description of a software package was lifted *verbatim* from the package's site itself.

It's a whole paragraph where not a single comma was changed. There are no quotations, nothing to indicate that this is a verbatim transcription of text. The site of the package is properly cited though, nothing is being hidden.

I understand that the description of a package created by the author is the best source to understand what that package does, but copy/pasting about 12 lines of text (single column) seems a bit excessive.

To what extent is this acceptable?

Comment: What do you mean, "an article". Is this a journal paper, an advertorial, something else?

Comment: It is a scientific paper in a well known indexed journal.

Comment: It is quite acceptable, provided it is stated where it came from, so the reader knows it is not due to the authors of the paper.

Answer (score 3):

As long as a proper reference and quotation indications are provided, there is nothing wrong with it - as with any other type of verbatim text copy. However; it is debatable whether this is a desirable approach, and this may vary with the traditions in individual fields.

If no reference is given it is (a mild form of) plagiarism.

Comment: There are no quotations. Nothing to indicate that this is a verbatim transcription of text. But there is a link to the package's site. Just added this to the question.

Comment: In that case, it is plagiarism, albeit a mild form (a reference is given).

Comment: There are no mild forms of plagiarism...

Answer (score 1):

There are a vast number of different citation standards, I assume the journal in question adheres to one of them. In most journals' implementation of the citation standards, it is denoted how a direct quote should be demarked, eg. with "" or >><< or *italics* etc.

If the article fails to live up to that, they are guilty of breaching the citation standard. Since we are talking about a full paragraph, but not anything were they present any deep thoughts, it is probably severe enough that it should be avoided, but definitely not severe enough to be punishable by any standards.